# Grunt un-css taking too much time when used with phantom js

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs

I am new to grunt and exploring it. Must say it's a great tool using it for css-uglify and js-uglify successfully.

Now I'm trying to learn un-css which need a css file and url for phantom-js to parse, i have around 242 urls. when i run grunt command, it is running for some time and then giving error like

```
evaluating open() call: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

This is how i read all url in an array

```
var _getAllFilesFromFolder = function(dir) {
var filesystem = require("fs");
var results = [];
filesystem.readdirSync(dir).forEach(function(file) {
    file = dir + '/' + file;
    var stat = filesystem.statSync(file);
    results.push('http://p1.localcdomain.in/' + file);        
});
return results;
```

};

```
var htmlPhpFileAll = _getAllFilesFromFolder("themes/html");
```

Here is my grunt file

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
      uncss: {
        in_css: {
            options: {
                stylesheets: [
                    '../../themes/ngCus/source/js/jquery-ui/css/no-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css',
                    '../../themes/ngCus/source/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css',
                    '../../themes/ngCus/source/css/font-icons/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
                    '../../themes/ngCus/source/js/selectboxit/jquery.selectBoxIt.css',
                    '../../themes/ngCus/source/js/select2/select2.css',
                    '../../themes/ngCus/source/js/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css',
                    '../../themes/ngCus/source/css/stylesheet.css',
                    '../../themes/ngCus/source/css/toaster.css',
                    '../../themes/ngCus/source/js/select/fancyfields.css',
                    '../../themes/ngCus/source/js/morris/morris-0.4.3.min.css',
                    '../../themes/ngCus/source/css/tabbed.css',
                    '../../themes/ngCus/source/css/contextmenu.css',
                    '../../themes/ngCus/source/css/font-icons/entypo/css/entypo.css'
                ],
                report: 'min',
                urls: htmlPhpFile,
            },
            files: {
                'themes/ngCus/source/css/app.clean.css': [
                    'themes/html/*.php',
                ]
            }
        },

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-uncss');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concat-css');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
//grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');

// grunt.registerTask('default', ["uglify:dist"]);
```

}

Comment: Could you provide the snippet of code that produces this error?

Comment: @KaarelNummert : please have look i have updated the code